# python kivy uix widget classes with "hidden" methods or properties?

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, kivy

Are there hidden methods for the widget classes included with kivy? I have been using kivy for several months and understand most things like the default atlas, bindings, and kivy properties.

My questions originates from my failed attempt to change the cursor image of the kivy.uix.slider.Slider widget. First of all, the documentation states that there should be string properties like "cursor_image" and "background_vertical" that point to the default atlas. The installed version does not even have these properties on the class. I went to [github](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/slider.py) and got the slider class. This does have the properties, so I tried to change them, no luck; It still looks the same. Here's where things get stranger. If I just rename the class from Slider to MySlider the widget does not even render!

Below is code pasted from github with the class name changed. If you change the name back to Slider in the class and assignment to root, it works fine. If I edit the default atlas image this will change the appearance, telling me that the Slider class always points to it. Also you will notice there are no uses of the atlas string properties in the class, telling me kivy is somehow assembling this widget's visible parts at run time using some default values. I have been through the widget's API and found nothing. Any idea what's going on?

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

"""
Slider
======
.. image:: images/slider.jpg
The :class:`Slider` widget looks like a scrollbar. It supports horizontal and
vertical orientations, min/max values and a default value.
To create a slider from -100 to 100 starting from 25::
    from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
    s = Slider(min=-100, max=100, value=25)
To create a vertical slider::
    from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
    s = Slider(orientation='vertical')
To create a slider with a red line tracking the value::
    from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
    s = Slider(value_track=True, value_track_color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
"""
__all__ = ('Slider', )

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import (NumericProperty, AliasProperty, OptionProperty,
                             ReferenceListProperty, BoundedNumericProperty,
                             StringProperty, ListProperty, BooleanProperty)


class MySlider(Widget):
    """Class for creating a Slider widget.
    Check module documentation for more details.
    """

    value = NumericProperty(0.)
    '''Current value used for the slider.
    :attr:`value` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.NumericProperty` and defaults
    to 0.'''

    min = NumericProperty(0.)
    '''Minimum value allowed for :attr:`value`.
    :attr:`min` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.NumericProperty` and defaults to
    0.'''

    max = NumericProperty(100.)
    '''Maximum value allowed for :attr:`value`.
    :attr:`max` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.NumericProperty` and defaults to
    100.'''

    padding = NumericProperty('16sp')
    '''Padding of the slider. The padding is used for graphical representation
    and interaction. It prevents the cursor from going out of the bounds of the
    slider bounding box.
    By default, padding is 16sp. The range of the slider is reduced from
    padding \*2 on the screen. It allows drawing the default cursor of 32sp
    width without having the cursor go out of the widget.
    :attr:`padding` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.NumericProperty` and defaults
    to 16sp.'''

    orientation = OptionProperty('horizontal', options=(
        'vertical', 'horizontal'))
    '''Orientation of the slider.
    :attr:`orientation` is an :class:`~kivy.properties.OptionProperty` and
    defaults to 'horizontal'. Can take a value of 'vertical' or 'horizontal'.
    '''

    range = ReferenceListProperty(min, max)
    '''Range of the slider in the format (minimum value, maximum value)::
        >>> slider = Slider(min=10, max=80)
        >>> slider.range
        [10, 80]
        >>> slider.range = (20, 100)
        >>> slider.min
        20
        >>> slider.max
        100
    :attr:`range` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty` of
    (:attr:`min`, :attr:`max`) properties.
    '''

    step = BoundedNumericProperty(0, min=0)
    '''Step size of the slider.
    .. versionadded:: 1.4.0
    Determines the size of each interval or step the slider takes between
    min and max. If the value range can't be evenly divisible by step the
    last step will be capped by slider.max
    :attr:`step` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.NumericProperty` and defaults
    to 1.'''

    background_horizontal = StringProperty(
        'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/sliderh_background')
    """Background of the slider used in the horizontal orientation.
    .. versionadded:: 1.10.0
    :attr:`background_horizontal` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.StringProperty`
    and defaults to `atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/sliderh_background`.
    """

    background_disabled_horizontal = StringProperty(
        'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/sliderh_background_disabled')
    """Background of the disabled slider used in the horizontal orientation.
    .. versionadded:: 1.10.0
    :attr:`background_disabled_horizontal` is a
    :class:`~kivy.properties.StringProperty` and defaults to
    `atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/sliderh_background_disabled`.
    """

    background_vertical = StringProperty(
        'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/sliderv_background')
    """Background of the slider used in the vertical orientation.
    .. versionadded:: 1.10.0
    :attr:`background_vertical` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.StringProperty`
    and defaults to `atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/sliderv_background`.
    """

    background_disabled_vertical = StringProperty(
        'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/sliderv_background_disabled')
    """Background of the disabled slider used in the vertical orientation.
    .. versionadded:: 1.10.0
    :attr:`background_disabled_vertical` is a
    :class:`~kivy.properties.StringProperty` and defaults to
    `atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/sliderv_background_disabled`.
    """

    background_width = NumericProperty('36sp')
    """Slider's background's width (thickness), used in both horizontal
    and vertical orientations.
    .. versionadded 1.10.0
    :attr:`background_width` is a
    :class:`~kivy.properties.NumericProperty` and defaults to 36sp.
    """

    cursor_image = StringProperty(
        'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/slider_cursor')
    """Path of the image used to draw the slider cursor.
    .. versionadded 1.10.0
    :attr:`cursor_image` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.StringProperty`
    and defaults to `atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/slider_cursor`.
    """

    cursor_disabled_image = StringProperty(
        'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/slider_cursor_disabled')
    """Path of the image used to draw the disabled slider cursor.
    .. versionadded 1.10.0
    :attr:`cursor_image` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.StringProperty`
    and defaults to `atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/slider_cursor_disabled`.
    """

    cursor_width = NumericProperty('32sp')
    """Width of the cursor image.
    .. versionadded 1.10.0
    :attr:`cursor_width` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.NumericProperty`
    and defaults to 32sp.
    """

    cursor_height = NumericProperty('32sp')
    """Height of the cursor image.
    .. versionadded 1.10.0
    :attr:`cursor_height` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.NumericProperty`
    and defaults to 32sp.
    """

    cursor_size = ReferenceListProperty(cursor_width, cursor_height)
    """Size of the cursor image.
    .. versionadded 1.10.0
    :attr:`cursor_size` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty`
    of (:attr:`cursor_width`, :attr:`cursor_height`) properties.
    """

    border_horizontal = ListProperty([0, 18, 0, 18])
    """Border used to draw the slider background in horizontal orientation.
    .. versionadded 1.10.0
    :attr:`border_horizontal` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.ListProperty`
    and defaults to [0, 18, 0, 18].
    """

    border_vertical = ListProperty([18, 0, 18, 0])
    """Border used to draw the slider background in vertical orientation.
    .. versionadded 1.10.0
    :attr:`border_horizontal` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.ListProperty`
    and defaults to [18, 0, 18, 0].
    """

    value_track = BooleanProperty(False)
    """Decides if slider should draw the line indicating the
    space between :attr:`min` and :attr:`value` properties values.
    .. versionadded 1.10.0
    :attr:`value_track` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.BooleanProperty`
    and defaults to False.
    """

    value_track_color = ListProperty([1, 1, 1, 1])
    """Color of the :attr:`value_line` in rgba format.
    .. versionadded 1.10.0
    :attr:`value_track_color` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.ListProperty`
    and defaults to [1, 1, 1, 1].
    """

    value_track_width = NumericProperty('3dp')
    """Width of the track line.
    .. versionadded 1.10.0
    :attr:`value_track_width` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.NumericProperty`
    and defaults to 3dp.
    """

    # The following two methods constrain the slider's value
    # to range(min,max). Otherwise it may happen that self.value < self.min
    # at init.

    def on_min(self, *largs):
        self.value = min(self.max, max(self.min, self.value))

    def on_max(self, *largs):
        self.value = min(self.max, max(self.min, self.value))

    def get_norm_value(self):
        vmin = self.min
        d = self.max - vmin
        if d == 0:
            return 0
        return (self.value - vmin) / float(d)

    def set_norm_value(self, value):
        vmin = self.min
        vmax = self.max
        step = self.step
        val = min(value * (vmax - vmin) + vmin, vmax)
        if step == 0:
            self.value = val
        else:
            self.value = min(round((val - vmin) / step) * step + vmin,
                             vmax)
    value_normalized = AliasProperty(get_norm_value, set_norm_value,
                                     bind=('value', 'min', 'max', 'step'))
    '''Normalized value inside the :attr:`range` (min/max) to 0-1 range::
        >>> slider = Slider(value=50, min=0, max=100)
        >>> slider.value
        50
        >>> slider.value_normalized
        0.5
        >>> slider.value = 0
        >>> slider.value_normalized
        0
        >>> slider.value = 100
        >>> slider.value_normalized
        1
    You can also use it for setting the real value without knowing the minimum
    and maximum::
        >>> slider = Slider(min=0, max=200)
        >>> slider.value_normalized = .5
        >>> slider.value
        100
        >>> slider.value_normalized = 1.
        >>> slider.value
        200
    :attr:`value_normalized` is an :class:`~kivy.properties.AliasProperty`.
    '''

    def get_value_pos(self):
        padding = self.padding
        x = self.x
        y = self.y
        nval = self.value_normalized
        if self.orientation == 'horizontal':
            return (x + padding + nval * (self.width - 2 * padding), y)
        else:
            return (x, y + padding + nval * (self.height - 2 * padding))

    def set_value_pos(self, pos):
        padding = self.padding
        x = min(self.right - padding, max(pos[0], self.x + padding))
        y = min(self.top - padding, max(pos[1], self.y + padding))
        if self.orientation == 'horizontal':
            if self.width == 0:
                self.value_normalized = 0
            else:
                self.value_normalized = (x - self.x - padding
                                         ) / float(self.width - 2 * padding)
        else:
            if self.height == 0:
                self.value_normalized = 0
            else:
                self.value_normalized = (y - self.y - padding
                                         ) / float(self.height - 2 * padding)
    value_pos = AliasProperty(get_value_pos, set_value_pos,
                              bind=('x', 'y', 'width', 'height', 'min',
                                    'max', 'value_normalized', 'orientation'))
    '''Position of the internal cursor, based on the normalized value.
    :attr:`value_pos` is an :class:`~kivy.properties.AliasProperty`.
    '''

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.disabled or not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return
        if touch.is_mouse_scrolling:
            if 'down' in touch.button or 'left' in touch.button:
                if self.step:
                    self.value = min(self.max, self.value + self.step)
                else:
                    self.value = min(
                        self.max,
                        self.value + (self.max - self.min) / 20)
            if 'up' in touch.button or 'right' in touch.button:
                if self.step:
                    self.value = max(self.min, self.value - self.step)
                else:
                    self.value = max(
                        self.min,
                        self.value - (self.max - self.min) / 20)
        else:
            touch.grab(self)
            self.value_pos = touch.pos
        return True

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current == self:
            self.value_pos = touch.pos
            return True

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current == self:
            self.value_pos = touch.pos
            return True

root = MySlider(orientation='vertical')

runTouchApp(root)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found where the kivy "magic" happens. The widgets do have bindings and images set based on the class name the style.kv file in the kivy/data/ directory here is a snippet from the Slider class

```
<Slider>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        BorderImage:
            border: (0, 18, 0, 18) if self.orientation == 'horizontal' else (18, 0, 18, 0)
            pos: (self.x + self.padding, self.center_y - sp(18)) if self.orientation == 'horizontal' else (self.center_x - 18, self.y + self.padding)
            size: (self.width - self.padding * 2, sp(36)) if self.orientation == 'horizontal' else (sp(36), self.height - self.padding * 2)
            source: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/slider{}_background{}'.format(self.orientation[0], '_disabled' if self.disabled else '')
        Rectangle:
            pos: (self.value_pos[0] - sp(16), self.center_y - sp(17)) if self.orientation == 'horizontal' else (self.center_x - (16), self.value_pos[1] - sp(16))
            size: (sp(32), sp(32))
            source: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/slider_cursor{}'.format('_disabled' if self.disabled else '')
```

What is interesting is that in the installed version of kivy (1.9.1) I have there are not atlas properties on the Slider class. The version on github claims these were added in version 1.10.0 but I think the master version on github is 1.9.2 so I'm confused there. Looking at a class that I am able to change (Button) I see the difference. You notice that in the snippet from style.kv file below that the file uses the kivy properties to set the state_image.

```
<-Button,-ToggleButton>:
    state_image: self.background_normal if self.state == 'normal' else self.background_down
    disabled_image: self.background_disabled_normal if self.state == 'normal' else self.background_disabled_down
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        BorderImage:
            border: self.border
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: self.disabled_image if self.disabled else self.state_image
        Color:
            rgba: self.disabled_color if self.disabled else self.color
        Rectangle:
            texture: self.texture
            size: self.texture_size
            pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)
```

I checked the master version of the build.kv and the slider has been updated to use the properties and does work as the API doc states. I hope this will help others.